# Copy fields from FormA to a new form FormB

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am trying to simplify an existing Notes Form in an application that I am converting to XPages. The Notes Form has over 240 fields on it and a bunch of logic that I want to clean up. Plus the form has all kinds of display formatting that makes viewing it complex. So what I have been trying to write an agent that will get FormA and cycle through all the fields and copy them to FormB. I will then use FormB to bind my XPage to and trying to track down data issues will be much simpler. If the FormA didn't have so many fields I would just recreate it manually, but I'm sure with over 240 fields I would introduce some new typo errors.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to use DXL. But what have you tried so far?  You say that you've been trying to write an agent, but you haven't given us any idea of how far you've gotten. Do you have code to show us and any specific questions about it?

Comment: I think in most cases it's not a good idea to have a form with 240 fields. It looks for me like an form from Notes 3 or 4 times when no embedded views were available and one to many relations were put into fields with index e.g. 1 to 20. Maybe, a redesign is a better way to go. You don't need to have a form with all 240 fields to use it as a data container for XPages.

Comment: BTW, you might be surprised that most of your 16 questions weren't answered. That has two reasons. **First**, you have to tag questions relating XPages with tag `xpages` because most of XPages' experts filter questions with that tag. So, usually questions tagged with `xpages` are viewed by 60 people within two days whereas your questions see only 10 or less people in a month. If `xpages` is not appropriate for a question then use other popular tags like `lotus-domino` or `lotus-notes`.

Comment: @Robert-harvey The question is clear now in the context of XPages, can you reopen the question so we can provide a meaningful answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, in most cases it's not a good idea to have a form with 240 fields. It looks for me like a form from old Notes 3 or 4 times when no embedded views were available and one to many relations were put into fields with index e.g. 1 to 20.

Maybe, a redesign is a better way to go.

Also, you don't need to create and maintain a form with all 240 fields for developing your XPage.  Actually, you don't need the form at all. With a data source definition based on "Domino Document" you define a form name and which way you want to create a new document or find an existing document. That's it. Then you can create your fields in your XPage. Give them a name and a type. You can do this in Designer UI. Just write the new fieldname into "Bind to" for selected "Data source". Select in "Display type" a field type (String, Number, Date/Time). That is not only valid for display but will save the field as selected type to document too. In this example it will create a new field "YourNewField" and will save it as a integer number.
[image]

When you submit the page all fields will be created or set in document. You can check the fields and their types in Notes client using the document property box.

A good way though is to create the form with the most important fields. Then you can open the document in Notes client and check the fields set by XPage.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything with your form in order to create a XPage layout for it. 
XPAges don't need a form at all, although it makes development easier, as after creating the data binding all fields from the form are available and can be dragged and dropped to the Xpage. Fields that are not on the form have to be created manually in the source code of the xpage (e.g. copy and paste an existing one and change the binding/name)

If you want to clean up your documents, an agent can do this without even touching the form.

For this task please consider the difference between a "Form" and a "Document".
A form is a design element that defines the look and feel of a document. 
Forms contain fields that define what type of data you can put in your documents.
A document is a stupid "container" for items (not fields). It contains items for any field on the form that existed in the form when the document was created / last saved. PLUS items that are created any other way (e.g. Using formula or lotusscript agents) or that have been on the form in an earlier stage of development.

If you remove a field from a form, it will NOT be removed from the corresponding documents, not even by saving them. But If you add a field to a form, the document will have an item for that field after saving (forever, if you don't remove it manually using an agent).

With this knowledge you can simply create a new, "cleaner" form with the same name as the old one and rename the old one. From this time on, document will be displayed with the new Form and you can develop your XPage using it as your data source.

If you need to accumulate the data in the documents, this can be done with an agent without using a form: just manipulate the document DIRECTLY.

Here is an example in formula to put two fields together:

```
FIELD NewFieldName := OldField_1 : OldField_2;
FIELD OldField_1 := @DeleteField;
FIELD OldField_2 := @DeleteField;
```